# Error making openwsman on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: c, linux, linker-errors, building, openwsman

I am trying to build openwsman (2.3.0 downloaded yesterday from the official website) on Ubunutu 12.04. I follow the instruction found in README.md and after installing several additional packages I finally got the command `cmake ..` to succeed.

However when I run `make` I get the following error:

```
Linking C executable test_list
../libwsman_curl_client_transport.so.1.0.0: undefined reference to `X509_digest'
../libwsman_curl_client_transport.so.1.0.0: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_cert_verify_callback'
../libwsman_curl_client_transport.so.1.0.0: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_verify'
../libwsman_curl_client_transport.so.1.0.0: undefined reference to `EVP_sha1'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [src/lib/test/test_list] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/lib/test/CMakeFiles/test_list.dir/all] Error 2
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally been able to resolve this issue. It turns out I needed to change a CMakeLists file in the openwsman library.

What I needed to change are the libraries linked with `libwsman_curl_client_transport`. To fix the issue open the file `src/lib/CMakeLists.txt`(assuming you are located in openwsman base directory) and change the line that looks like:

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( wsman_curl_client_transport ${CURL_LIBRARIES})
```

To

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( wsman_curl_client_transport ${CURL_LIBRARIES} ssl crypto)
```

In the openwsman distribution I have downloaded(openwsman2.3.0) this is line 53 of the file described.

In what I do here is I tell the given library to be linked with crypto and ssl too and this resolves the linker errors.

Hope this answer helps someone to resolve this issue way faster than I did.